# Finding roots of a non linear expression when multiplied with a linear expression

Tags: python, matlab

Here is a simple polynomial equation:

```
b^2 + 2b + 1 = 0
```

I could easily solve this as:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

eq = lambda b : np.power(b,2) + 2*b + 1
fsolve(eq, np.linspace(0,1,2))
```

Similarly, I could solve any equation that has finite number of terms. But how do I solve an equation with infinite number of terms which is given as:

$G_t^{\lambda}=(1-\lambda) \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda^{n-1}G_{t:t+n}$

The above equation could be written as:

```
(1 - l) * (5.5 + 4.0*l + 4*l^2 + 6*l^3 + 5*l^4 + 5*l^5 + 5*l^6 + 5*l^7 + 5*l^8 + 5*l^9 + 5*l^10   ) = 5
```

when n goes from 1 to 10. But I want to solve this for sufficiently large value of `n` such that LHS ~= RHS.

I know the values of LHS and `G1 -> Ginf` but cannot understand how could I compute the value of lambda here.

I tried looking at [numpy polynomial functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html) but could not find a function that is relevant here.

Comment: Please explain what G_t and G_t:t+n are.

Comment: @Paul G_t is a constant. In the example equation given above it equals the RHS which is `5`. G_t:t+n are also pre-computed constants which in LHS are given as 5.5, 4,4,6,5,,5. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: This seems off-topic to me, unless there's a connection to a DS problem you have in mind?  Ultimately you're asking how to find zeros of a function given its power series representation, which is probably best for the Math SE (although you're perhaps more interested in computational approaches, and I'm not sure then whether there's a better place).  [If, as in your example, the coefficients are eventually periodic, then it's relatively easy to use geometric series to express the equation more compactly.]

Comment: Do you have a formula for `G_t:t+n` as a function of `n` and/or `λ`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this equation can be solved in general. Since it is an infinitely long polynomial, it cannot be evaluated. It can only be done if the constants $G_{t:t+n}$ followed a very specific pattern, so that the series becomes equivalent to a known function that we can evaluate. For example:

- If $G_{t:t+n}$ were equal to $[ 1, {1\over2}!, {1\over3}!, {1\over4}!, ...]$ (where $4!$ is the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of $4$), then the [sum would be equal to](http://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-3-power-series/taylor-series/maclaurin-expansion-of-ex/) $e^\lambda$
- If $G_{t:t+n}$ were equal to $[1, 0, {-1\over3}!, 0, {1\over5}!, ...]$ then [the sum would be equal to](http://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-3-power-series/taylor-series/maclaurin-expansion-of-sinx/) $\sin(\lambda)$

But in general, if $G$ were any random set of constants, the function cannot be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You may apply [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) to your project. There is a free [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/developer/) for developers and with the [Wolfram Client Library for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) you can use these functions.

If you have $G_{t:t+n}$ as a function of n and/or λ then the roots can be found if they exist.  No amount of memory can store an infinite number of pre-calculated constants so some formula for $G_{t:t+n}$ must be provided.

Let

```
g[n_, λ_] := λ/n
```

An infinite [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) can be evaluated symbolically in the limit. By [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) some conditions on `λ` to insure convergence. Then

```
Assuming[
 0 < λ < 1,
 (1 - λ) Sum[λ^(n - 1) g[n, λ], {n, 1, Infinity}]
 ]
```

> ```
> -(1 - λ) Log[1 - λ]
> ```

If using [Wolfram's notebook interface](http://www.wolfram.com/notebooks/) then there is the option of entering this problem in mathematical notation.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Taking a `g` from @Paul without assumptions.

```
g[n_,λ_] := 1/n!
res = Sum[λ^(n - 1) g[n, λ], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> ((-1+E^λ) (1-λ))/λ
> ```

Then use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) (or [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)) on `res` for the family of solutions.  [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) is used to make finding inverse solutions easier.

```
Solve[Reduce[res == 5], λ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The family of solutions is return as a [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) with $c_{1}$ in the set of integers.

Hope this helps.